# How to read from a text file in MySQL using delimiter

Tags: mysql

I know you can use the LOAD DATA command in MySQL to load data from a file into a database table, but that's using the default delimiters of whitespace.

I'm loading text from a file that contains words as well as punctuation. I need to load the words in the database but ignore any punctuation. In a language like C#, I would just specify a regular expression that only grabs alphanumeric characters and ignores other symbols.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL commands as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to enclose your strings in quotes in the file and specify the

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

optional parameter. For example your data would be

```
"xxx","Some text, and some more!", ...
```

I don't know of another way to do it in MySQL.

See the ENCLOSED BY section of this documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html